# Can't find any node using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have `[Content_Types].xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/xml"/>
  <Default Extension="jpeg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
  <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
  <Default Extension="jpg" ContentType="image/jpeg"/>
  <Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/customXml/itemProps1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/webSettings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/footnotes.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footnotes+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/endnotes.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.endnotes+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/header1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/footer1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/header2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/footer2.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
</Types>
```

I've loaded it using Nokogiri:

```
doc = File.open("[Content_Types].xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
```

I want to find the `<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>` node but I can't find anything:

```
irb(main):048:0> doc.xpath('//Default')
=> []
irb(main):049:0> doc.xpath('//Override')
=> []
irb(main):050:0> doc.xpath('//Types')
=> []
irb(main):051:0> doc.xpath('Types')
=> []
```

Why?

The xml is loaded correctly:

```
irb(main):003:0> doc
=>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fcddd413ad0 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd41347c name="Types" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd412f18 "\n\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd412e14 name="Default" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd412d9c name="Extension" value="xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd412d88 name="ContentType" value="application/xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd4126bc "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd413558 name="Default" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40ffac name="Extension" value="rels">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40ff84 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd40ef08 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd40eddc name="Default" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40ecec name="Extension" value="jpeg">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40ecc4 name="ContentType" value="image/jpeg">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd40bca4 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd40bb78 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40bac4 name="PartName" value="/word/document.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40ba88 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd40a8cc "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd40a7f0 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40a778 name="PartName" value="/word/styles.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd40a764 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd099d00 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd099bc0 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd099b34 name="PartName" value="/word/settings.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd099b20 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd098e8c "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd098d60 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd098cc0 name="PartName" value="/word/webSettings.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd098cac name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd08ded8 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd08dd98 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd08dce4 name="PartName" value="/word/fontTable.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd08dca8 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd08cdf8 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd08cd1c name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd08cc54 name="PartName" value="/word/theme/theme1.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd08cc40 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd08c0d8 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd08c010 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd089fa4 name="PartName" value="/docProps/core.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd089f90 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcddd089388 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcddd089248 name="Override" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fcddd4133b4 href="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd089144 name="PartName" value="/docProps/app.xml">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcddd089130 name="ContentType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml">]>]>]>
```

Comment: you spelled "Default" as "Deafult" in your console example

Comment: @SimpleLime That was a typo in question - it is corrected now. Thanks for spotting it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the ["Searching a XML/HTML document"](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) page on the Nokogiri site, there's an ATOM example

> Let’s take this atom feed for example:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
>   <title>Example Feed</title>
>   <link href="http://example.org/"/>
>   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
>   <author>
>     <name>John Doe</name>
>   </author>
>   <id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b93C-0003939e0af6</id>
>   <entry>
>     <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
>     <link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03"/>
>     <id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id>
>     <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
>     <summary>Some text.</summary>
>   </entry>
> </feed>
> ```
>
> If we stick to the convention, we can grab all title tags like this
>
> ```
> @doc.xpath('//xmlns:title') # => ["<title>Example Feed</title>", "<title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>"]
> ```

Since your example input has

```
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
```

It should work to do

```
puts doc.xpath("//xmlns:Default[@Extension='png']")
# <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
```

Alternatively, you can use `css` instead

```
puts doc.css("Types Default[Extension='png']")
# <Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>
```

There's also a section on the page about [not dealing with namespaces](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#but_i_m_lazy_and_don_t_want_to_deal_with_namespaces_) if you're interested